# I generate application with Jhipster 8.0.0-beta.2 but sonar analysis appears error

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube, jhipster

###### **Overview of the issue**

I generate application with Jhipster 8.0.0-beta.2 but sonar analysis appears error, when execute in jenkins file.

###### **Motivation for or Use Case**

I need sonar analysis.

###### **Reproduce the error**

Generate jhipster application with generator and jdl generator entities
Execute in jenkins with jenkinsfile. Appears this error in stage quality analysis:

```
[INFO]  
[INFO] --- properties:1.1.0:read-project-properties (default) @ establishment-catalog ---  
[INFO]  
[INFO] --- jacoco:0.8.10:prepare-agent (pre-unit-tests) @ establishment-catalog ---  
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.10/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.10-runtime.jar=destfile=/mnt/data/jenkins/workspace/establishment-catalog_sonar/target/jacoco.exec -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx1G  
[INFO]  
[INFO] -----\< com.jumbotours.establishmentcatalog:establishment-catalog \>------  
[INFO] Building Establishment Catalog 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT  
[INFO] from pom.xml  
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------  
[INFO]  
[INFO] --- sonar:3.9.1.2184:sonar (default-cli) @ establishment-catalog ---  
[INFO] User cache: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache  
[INFO] SonarQube version: 7.9.1  
[INFO] Default locale: "es_ES", source code encoding: "UTF-8"  
[INFO] Load global settings  
[INFO] Load global settings (done) | time=80ms  
[INFO] Server id: A7EE8CF2-AXIr741RGzh0g1Z-gz91  
[INFO] User cache: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache  
[INFO] Load/download plugins  
[INFO] Load plugins index  
[INFO] Load plugins index (done) | time=49ms  
[INFO] Load/download plugins (done) | time=78ms  
[INFO] Process project properties  
[INFO] Execute project builders  
[INFO] Execute project builders (done) | time=3ms  
[INFO] Project key: establishment-catalog:sonar  
[INFO] Base dir: /mnt/data/jenkins/workspace/establishment-catalog_sonar  
[INFO] Working dir: /mnt/data/jenkins/workspace/establishment-catalog_sonar/target/sonar  
[INFO] Load project settings for component key: 'establishment-catalog:sonar'  
[INFO] Load project settings for component key: 'establishment-catalog:sonar' (done) | time=19ms  
[INFO] Load quality profiles  
[INFO] Load quality profiles (done) | time=43ms  
[INFO] Detected Jenkins  
[INFO] Load active rules  
[INFO] Load active rules (done) | time=406ms  
[INFO] Indexing files...  
[INFO] Project configuration:  
[INFO] Excluded sources: src/main/webapp/content//., src/main/webapp/i18n/\*.js, target/classes/static//., src/test//.  
[INFO] Included tests: src/test//.  
[INFO] 153 files indexed  
[INFO] 0 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns  
[INFO] 0 files ignored because of scm ignore settings  
[INFO] Quality profile for java: Sonar way jumbo  
[INFO] Quality profile for web: Sonar way  
[INFO] Quality profile for xml: Sonar way  
[INFO] ------------- Run sensors on module establishment-catalog:sonar  
[INFO] Load metrics repository  
[INFO] Load metrics repository (done) | time=20ms  
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------  
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE  
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------  
[INFO] Total time: 5.142 s  
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-10T18:03:11+02:00  
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------  
[WARNING]  
[WARNING] Plugin validation issues were detected in 3 plugin(s)  
[WARNING]  
[WARNING] \* org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.10  
[WARNING] \* org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184  
[WARNING] \* org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.1  
[WARNING]  
[WARNING] For more or less details, use 'maven.plugin.validation' property with one of the values (case insensitive): [BRIEF, DEFAULT, VERBOSE]  
[WARNING]  
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar (default-cli) on project establishment-catalog: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null  
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------  
[ERROR] realm = plugin\>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184  
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy  
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.9.1.2184/sonar-maven-plugin-3.9.1.2184.jar  
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar  
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar  
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.2.1/plexus-utils-3.2.1.jar  
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api/2.16.2.588/sonar-scanner-api-2.16.2.588.jar  
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar  
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1  
[ERROR] import: Entry[import from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]  
[ERROR]  
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------  
[ERROR] : java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException--\>Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @1c5cd2ea  
[ERROR] -\> [Help 1]  
[ERROR]  
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.  
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.  
[ERROR]  
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:  
[ERROR] [Help 1] <http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException>  
[Pipeline] }  
WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succeeded?
```

###### **JHipster Version(s)**

Jhipster 8.0.0-beta.2

###### **Browsers and Operating System**

All Operating System, all browsers

###### **Jenkins File**

I need solved the problem